# Scaling a polygon with the screen

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, scale, transformation

I need to scale polygons with the size of my screen. Originally the polygons are created on a canvas with a size of 640x480. I would like to scale them down or up to a new resolution of whatever I desire and maintain their relative positions and sizes. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    this.scale = function (x1, y1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            this.points[i].x *= x1;
            this.points[i].y *= y1;
        }
    }
```

Where x1 and y1 equal the new size of the screen divided by the original size. The issue I am facing is that the polygons appear to be offset from where they should be relative to an image. I also tried translating the vectors first before scaling and then translating them back to the original centroid using(pseudocode):

```
centroid = points / number of points

points = points - centroid
points = points * scale
points = points + centroid
```

This further offsets the polygons from where they should be relative to the image drawn on the canvas. Is there something I am missing here?

Edit: Added an example image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGeSw.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: The actual JS code you give would of course move the center of the figure, as you say. It would be correct correct to subtract the center, scale, then add the center again. I assume you checked to make sure you correctly implemented the calculation for the center of the polygon, and that the result it's producing is sensible? You should provide the actual JS code for that.

Comment: Incidentally, do you really need to [calculate a centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graboid), or would you be just as happy with the center point of the figure's bounding box?

Comment: Are you shure that your centroid is correct? Try to paint it on the canvas just to validate that it is correct.... Just points / _number_ of points doesn't seem enough to me.

Comment: A little off-topic, but are you doing the translation and the scale-stuff by yourself? You could use canvasContext.scale() and canvasContext.translate(). If you want to apply the transfromations only on sigle shapes you can use the state-stack: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transformation-state-stack-tutorial/

Comment: Ed Plunkett: I draw the polygons to a canvas with their centroids. I'm sure they are correct. Could it be though that because the screen has scaled too the centroid should be moved?

Treeno: I am sure, I have validated it's correct by drawing it to a canvas. Also I need to be able to scale the polygons themselves, not the canvas as I am interacting with them with mouse inputs.

Comment: @JohnM. A point at 100,100 is in the center of a 200x200 screen, but in the upper left corner of a 1024x728 screen. Which is to say, the JS you give should be correct. How large is the error, fiddly or dramatic? Is the screen aspect ratio changing, and (forgive me, this sounds much too obvious to mention) are you definitely using the same scale fator for the image and the polygons? Is the image definitely being scaled relative to 0,0? If the image is offset to 12,12 by CSS that'll throw everything off.

Comment: The scale factor is the same for the image and the polygons. I did find a 5 pixel margin on the canvas that was causing some issues, but the polygons still appear wrong after correcting that. It seems that they aren't tall enough so I am wondering it it's an aspect ratio issue? My original size is 640x480 this get's changed to 708x408. Should I change the aspect ratio of the original size first to match the new aspect ratio and then calculate the difference? I'm going to give that a shot.

Comment: I tested changing the original size to match the new aspect ratio and then calculating the difference from that to scale my polygons, but it only seemed to make the problem worse.

Comment: @JohnM. Looking at the image, I was wondering about the aspect ratio. It looks like the background image's aspect ratio is changing due to cropping, not stretching -- it appears the background image is being scaled by the same factor along the x and y axes. If that's correct, you want to do the same with the polygon. But it looks like the polygon is actually getting taller and narrower.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply all points by the scaling factor of the canvas.

[image][image]

Example Code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/xEqU5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var scale=1.00;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/scale8.jpg";
    function start(){
        drawAtScale();
    }

    function drawAtScale(){
        canvas.width=img.width*scale;
        canvas.height=img.height*scale;
        drawImage();
        drawPoly();
    }

    function drawImage(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width*scale,img.height*scale);
    }


    function drawPoly(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.lineWidth=3;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(185*scale,46*scale);
        ctx.lineTo(269*scale,53*scale);
        ctx.lineTo(621*scale,170*scale);
        ctx.lineTo(630*scale,329*scale);
        ctx.lineTo(382*scale,304*scale);
        ctx.lineTo(163*scale,234*scale);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle="gold";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }


    $("#smaller").click(function(){
        scale/=1.10;
        drawAtScale();
    });
    $("#larger").click(function(){
        scale*=1.10;
        drawAtScale();
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="smaller">Scale Canvas Smaller</button>
    <button id="larger">Scale Canvas Larger</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking to resize the polygons themselves, and not the canvas.

Comment: Yes, however I need to interact with these polygons using mouse input. The polygons themselves are only displayed for debugging purposes. Using the canvas's transformation functions doesn't really help with that.

Comment: First adjust the points of each polygon to be relative to its centerpoint (or for irregular polys, relative to its declared centerpoint/centroid).  Do this by subtracting centerX & centerY from each poly point.  For each polygon: context.translate(polyCenterX,polyCenterY) and context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor) and then redraw the polygon at its original size. Note: context scale will do all the resizing and repositioning for you as long as the poly points are relative to the poly's centerpoint. Cheers!

Comment: Not understanding what you want :-/

Comment: I've added a example image to the question. Does this help at all?

Comment: So you want to scale both the background image and the foreground red polygon with the red dot being the origin of scaling?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue. I was scaling correctly however when the shapes were being created they were being created on a differently sized image which had black boxes at the top causing an offset.

Using a simple translation fixed the issue. The code looked something like this:

```
    //My offset.
    this.translate(-10, -50);

    this.translate = function (x1, y1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            this.points[i].x += x1;
            this.points[i].y += y1;
        }
    }
```